# How to automatically reopen a CHM file at the last reading position?

Tags: chm, persistence

There is a wealth of information packed inside .CHM files (HTML help), many books have been published as CHM files. However, it is difficult to read CHM files like a book, because when I reopen the same CHM file the next day (after having rebooted Windows), the reading position from the day before has been lost, and I have to awkwardly reopen chapters and sub-chapters to search and find the position where I stopped to read the day before.

So is there any trick or a tool or something else to reopen a CHM file at the same reading position where I left it the last time?

Comment: A short Google search for "bookmark CHM" brings some application which seem to be able handling this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you some Apps will convert CHM to PDF which more easy. so you can open with Adobe and do whatever you want whenever you want!

http://www.zamzar.com/convert/chm-to-pdf/

or use this one to convert to putr html so you can open from browser and bookmark the page

http://www.chmviewer.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've found this list of CHM viewers:

[List of CHM readers and viewers for Windows](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/articles/chm-reader-viewer-for-windows.html)

(Didn't know that there are other programs able to show CHM).

Already the first application was a full hit: SUMATRAPDF, which can also read CHM files. It is EXTREMELY fast, after program start it shows the last loaded documents on the main window, and AUTOMATICALLY restores the last read chapter! PERFECT!!!